# show ngx spinner after 1 second

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a centeralized interceptor which logs all http requests and also loads ngx-spinner for each request. Now, I want loader to be delayed 1 second after http request and if response is still in progress, then show spinner. If response is reached less than 1 second, then no spinner.

My Current Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    count = 0;
    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
        console.log(spinner);
    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       setTimeout(()=>{
           console.log(this.isRequestServed);
            this.spinner.show();
            this.count++;
       return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event=>{console.log("change");
        console.log(event)},error=>console.log(error)),
       finalize(()=>{   
            this.count--;
            if(this.count == 0)
             this.spinner.hide();

       }));
    }

}
```

Please let me know your thoughts on my requirement. Thanks.

Updating code using timeout, but spinner or loader does not show due to the boolean.

```
export class SampleInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    count = 0;
    isRequestServed: boolean;
    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
        console.log(spinner);
    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       setTimeout(()=>{
        if(this.isRequestServed == false) {
            this.spinner.show();
                this.count++;
        }
       },9000);
       return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event=>{this.isRequestServed = true;
        console.log(event)},error=>console.log(error)),
       finalize(()=>{
           if(this.count > 0 ) {    
            this.count--;
            if(this.count == 0)
             this.spinner.hide();
           }
       }));
    }

}
```

I am using a boolean to identify whether response is served or not.

I have fixed it by checking instance of event to HttpResponse.
Below is the code

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event=>{
        if(event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.isRequestServed = true;
        }},error=>console.log(error)),
```

This block of code in intercept return method solved issue. Thanks for input.

Comment: Put the spinner show part in a timeout, store it in a variable, and cancel it when the request finishes to prevent it from running if the request finishes early.

Comment: Hai Taplar, could you check my timeout code.

Comment: Ok, so you got a timeout now, but you need to store it in a variable.  So that later you can `clearTimeout(thatVariable)` in the case you want to prevent it from happening

Comment: @Vipul why do you use setTimeout instead of observables?

Comment: @grzim I am not looking for http request timeout, I need to show spinner after 1 second delay(not delaying http request BTW), before response is returned.

Comment: Solved issue, Updated fix in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const time = 900;
    const spinnerLogic = () => {
        if (this.isRequestServed == false) {
            this.spinner.show();
            this.count++;
        }
    };
    const onDataReceive = () => {
        this.isRequestServed = true;
        if (this.count > 0) {
            this.count--;
            if (this.count == 0)
                this.spinner.hide();
        }
    };
    // get a stream with a response
    const res$ = next.handle(req);
    // create a ctream with a function to show spinner and delay it for given time
    const timeout$ = of(spinnerLogic).pipe(delay(time));
    // if response cames before spinner nothing happens ( () => {} will be called instead of a one the to show spinner)
    const spinner$ = merge(res$.pipe(mapTo(() => {})), timeout$).pipe(first());
    // call function - showSpinner or () => {}
    spinner$.subscribe(f => f());
    // i gues you have in HTML | async. If not instead of pipe(finalize) subscribe should be used 
    return res$.pipe(finalize(onDataReceive));
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-t34vu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks for the code. Do you have chance to explain above code?

Comment: I am not good at rxjs, I copy pasted above code, spinner does not show. Could you explain above code?

Comment: sorry, it was the middle of the night for me. 
I have added comments and provided a demo.