# how to show ngx spinner after 1 second?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-observables

**I have doubts regarding the answer I have found on this platform.**

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const time = 900;
    const spinnerLogic = () => {
        if (this.isRequestServed == false) {
            this.spinner.show();
            this.count++;
        }
    };
    const onDataReceive = () => {
        this.isRequestServed = true;
        if (this.count > 0) {
            this.count--;
            if (this.count == 0)
                this.spinner.hide();
        }
    };
    // get a stream with a response
    const res$ = next.handle(req);
    // create a ctream with a function to show spinner and delay it for given time
    const timeout$ = of(spinnerLogic).pipe(delay(time));
    // if response cames before spinner nothing happens ( () => {} will be called instead of a one the to show spinner)
    const spinner$ = merge(res$.pipe(mapTo(() => {})), timeout$).pipe(first());
    // call function - showSpinner or () => {}
    spinner$.subscribe(f => f());
    // i gues you have in HTML | async. If not instead of pipe(finalize) subscribe should be used 
    return res$.pipe(finalize(onDataReceive));
}
```

following is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61899798

I follow the same code but I am confused where we have to assign **this.isRequestServed = false** in the code.

I tried initializing globally but the spinner is going in the loop.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the boolean var here may be solve the pblm

```
//Ur code...
if (this.count == 0){
this.spinner.hide();
this.isRequestServed=false
}
// Ur code
```

Comment: that didn't work.  do you have any idea  where I can define  this.isRequestServed = false. so that the spinnerLogic condition is satisfied ?

Comment: I edit the response , what happened!